# Install update from a different repository than google play

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I built an app for a client, but it must be private so I can't publish it in the store.
This application is installed in 30 devices, so every time I release some updates another guy has to install the new app in every device. I was wondering if I could update the app from a link or something.

My idea is to insert in a table the current version with the link of the app that expo provides me after the build.
Once I press the button "check for updates" I check the version installed and if it's old, I will download the app from the link and install it automatically.

Is it possible at least for Android? For ios I don't care so much since it is installed only in one device.
I read about updates from expo wiki but I think it works only for published apps

thanks

Comment: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mikehardy/react-native-update-apk), best option I could find

Answer (score 0):

Put the .apk on a server in the internet.

Everytime your app starts it starts a thread that checks if the .apk on the internet is different/newer from the one that is running.

If so then the new one is downloaded automatically.

When all done your app starts an install intent at a suitable moment.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play can distribute private app to devices registered in your organization.

You can read this for more info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en